Issues with expo-media-library and expo-image-picker after Updating to Target SDK 35 in Expo SDK 47 Project
I'm currently working on a React Native project using Expo SDK 47. Due to Google Play's requirements, I had to update my targetSdkVersion to 35 in my build.gradle file. My current build settings are:
buildToolsVersion = '33.0.0'
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 35

Checked Compatibility: I reviewed the Expo documentation and changelogs, but there's no clear information on whether these libraries fully support targetSdkVersion 35 in Expo SDK 47.

Tested in the App: After updating the target SDK, the media-related functionalities are either broken or behave inconsistently.

Explored Upgrade Options: Unfortunately, upgrading Expo to a newer version isn't feasible for me right now due to the size and complexity of the project.

Is there a known compatibility issue with expo-media-library and expo-image-picker when using targetSdkVersion 35?

Should I consider migrating to external libraries like react-native-image-picker or react-native-media-library that are independent of Expo's versioning?

If I do switch to an external library, what are the potential challenges or pitfalls I should be aware of, given that my project is deeply integrated with Expo?




